# Calling Stored Procedure while passing parameters from Access Module in VBA

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access, stored-procedures

I am working in Access 2010 with a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 backend.  I have a stored procedure that inserts new values(supplied by the parameters) into a table.  The values assigned to the parameters are obtained from files stored in a folder. The Windows File System is used to scan a particular folder to make a list of the files in it.  For each scanned file the stored procedure is called and the FileName and QueueId (Filename without extension) along with other values are used as parameters for the stored procedure called.  The stored procedure is used to create new records for each file for a table.

```
Public Function CreateInstrumentInterfaceLogRecords(BatchID As Long, InstrumentName As            String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo HandleError

Dim objFSO As FileSystemObject
Dim AllFiles As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim FileExt As String
Dim strSQL As String

CreateInstrumentInterfaceLogRecords = False
strSQL = "SELECT FileExt FROM tlkpInstrument"
FileExt = ExecuteScalar(strSQL)


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(NewPath) 

'NewPath is a public variable that holds the path to the folder'

Set AllFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile In AllFiles

FileName = objFile.FileName
QuenueId = Replace(FileName, FileExt, "")

'call procedure to pass values'

Next objFile

ExitProc:
Exit Function
HandleError:
MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description & " in CreateInstrumentInterfaceLogRecords"
GoTo ExitProc

End Function
```

and the stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE upInsertToInstrumentInterfaceLog @BatchID nvarchar(60),@InstrumentName nvarchar(60) ,@FIleName nvarchar(60), @QueueId nvarchar(60) 
AS
INSERT INTO tblInstrumentInterfaceLog (BatchID,InstrumentName,FileName,QueueID,DateOfBatch,Folder)
VALUES (@BatchID, @InstrumentName,@FileName, @QueueId,getdate(),'New');
GO
```

All the examples haven't really given me a solid idea of to create the connection and call the procedure.  Some advice I have been given is to study how ExecuteNonquery works so I have been trying to find examples related to that. The following is one of the example templates I've found

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection 
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command 

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection 
conn.ConnectionString = “your connection String here” 
conn.Open 

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command 
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn 
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc 
cmd.CommandText = "put stored procedure name here" 

cmd.Execute 
conn.Close 

Set conn = Nothing 
Set cmd = Nothing
```

I am not really sure what I should take from this example and how to incorporate passing values.  Also even though I have visited http://www.connectionstrings.com/ I am still confused on how to make them.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is your specific question?  Are you asking how to pass values from a VBA procedure to a stored procedure and call it?

Comment: yes, sorry for not clarifying.  My question is how do I pass values to, and call a stored procedure.

Comment: MSDN has an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675869%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185125

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection 
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command 

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection 
conn.ConnectionString = “your connection String here” 
conn.Open 

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command 
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn 
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc 
cmd.CommandText = "upInsertToInstrumentInterfaceLog" 

cmd.parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@BatchID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 60, "value for BatchID")   
cmd.parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@InstrumentName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 60, "value for InstrumentName")   
'...

cmd.Execute 
conn.Close
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a saved pass-though query.

You code then becomes:

```
With currentdb.querydefs("MyPass")
  .sql = "exec StoreProcName " & strBach & “,” & strInstrmentName
  .execute
End With
```

So, you only need two lines of code here. You don't even have to declare any connection strings or even any variables if you use a saved pass-through query.

Comment: What if strInstrumentName or strFileName have characters like ' or -- or even white spaces?

Comment: The rules are the same for any sproc you type into SQL server and how t-sql works. The above assumed a number parameter. If it is text, then the function should return its value surrounded by single quotes, or they can be added to above with "'" & MyFunction() & "'"