# How to feed an update stored procedure's decimal input parameter (could be null) by ADO VBA

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a template in Excel for customers to bulk update a SQL Server database.

The tricky part is with a few numeric columns, for example, the one I am testing is `Estimated_Amt`. The value could be null, and I tried and still cannot figure out if when it is null, how to pass the value to fee an update stored procedure.

Here's How I set up the parameter:

```
Estimated_Amt  = .Cells(iRowNo,8)

If (.Cells(iRowNo, 8) = "") Then
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Estimated_Amt", adVarChar, adParamInput, DBNULL.Value)
Else
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Estimated_Amt", adVarChar, adParamInput, CStr(Estimated_Amt))
End If
```

I tried `AdDouble` and `AdDecimal` respectively, and never succeeded in catching without error the null or empty value, and with `AdVarchar`, still didn't work out correctly

And the calling procedure part is like:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SP_RIBulkyUpdate @CaseNumber = " &     CaseNumber & ", " & _
"@Estimated_Amt = " & Estimated_Amt
```

Any suggestion on setting the input parameter correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `DBNULL.Value`, you could try `vbNullString` or `Null` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbnullstring(v=vs.110).aspx)
i.e.

```
...
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Estimated_Amt", adVarChar, adParamInput, Null)
...
```

Comment: Thank you. I guessed vbNullString could work and still got Type mismatch erro

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24248870/calling-stored-procedure-while-passing-parameters-from-access-module-in-vba) where the `CommandType` is set `cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc` and `CommandText` is set to the stored procedure name, i.e.,  `cmd.CommandText = "SP_RIBulkyUpdate"`.

Comment: I see what you meant, I just tried to specify cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoreProc, but some how the CreateParameter part didn't work out, parameters were not fed properly. Do you have some example about calling an update stored proc?

Comment: Have you tried to resemble this example? http://stackoverflow.com/a/24249331/5251960