# Cannot find the Nvarchar to Int conversion in my code

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, stored-procedures

I am currently making a project for school where I have to make a program where I can create orders in.
When I try to create orders I get this error returned to me.

Error converting Data Type Nvarchar to Int.

In advance I'm sorry if this is a really basic question that is easely spotted. Me and my project members are beginning programmers but we simply cannot spot where this goes wrong.

The code we execute in vba is this :

```
Set rs = DbConn.Execute("EXEC spOrderPlaatsen '" & Me.tbTijd & "', " & Me.klantnr & ", '" & Me.tbOphaaldatum & "', '" & Me.tbAfleverdatum & "', '" & Me.tbOphaaladres & "', " & Me.tbPalletnr & ", " & Me.tbAantalpallets & "")
```

This code execute's our Stored procedure.
The stored procedure looks like this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spOrderPlaatsen
(  
@tijd               time(0),
@klantnr            integer,
@ophaaldatum        date,
@afleverdatum       date,

@palletnr   integer,
@aantal     integer,
@Adres      Varchar(255)

) 
AS 

BEGIN TRANSACTION 

DECLARE @ordernr int
DECLARE @besteldatum date

set @besteldatum = getdate()

SELECT @ordernr = MAX(o.ordernr) + 1 
FROM orders o 

insert into orders values (@ordernr, @besteldatum, @tijd, @klantnr, @ophaaldatum, @afleverdatum, @adres)
insert into orderregel values (@ordernr, @palletnr, @aantal)

IF @@ERROR <> 0 
BEGIN 

ROLLBACK 

RAISERROR ('Error tijdens het plaatsen van order.', 16, 1) 
RETURN 
END 

COMMIT
go
```

Somehow we get a conversion error that we cannot find.

Could any1 figure this out for us? It would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This code looks like SQL Server, not MS Access. Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: For the VBA part: `Debug.Print` your SQL statement, see [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple places where this could be going wrong.  Here is some advice:

1. Execute the stored procedure with explicit parameters (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24248870/calling-stored-procedure-while-passing-parameters-from-access-module-in-vba) for an example).  Do not *ever* just dump the parameters into the query string.
2. Always list the columns for an `insert`.  So, this should be `insert into orders(col1, col2, col3, . . .)` for whatever columns you are including.
3. Use `identity` so `ordernr` is calculated automatically by the database.  You can get the value using an `OUTPUT` clause in the `INSERT`.
4. Similarly, you might want `besteldatum` to default to the current date -- or not.  I'm not sure what this column really is, but a default would be appropriate for a create date column.
5. Surround the entire body of the stored procedure in its own `BEGIN`/`END` block (don't depend on the `BEGIN TRANSACTION`.