# Access VBA Parameter in passthrough query to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, parameters, pass-through

I have several queries in an MS Access database. Some of these use parameters. I use the following code in VBA to provide the query with these parameters:

**VBA**

```vb
Dim startDate As Date
Dim endDate As Date

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

If IsNull(Me.dpFrom) Or IsNull(Me.dpTo) Then
    MsgBox "Please select a date!"
ElseIf (Me.dpFrom.Value > Me.dpTo.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Start date is bigger than the end date!"
Else
    startDate = Me.dpFrom.Value
    endDate = Me.dpTo.Value

    Set dbs = CurrentDb

    'Get the parameter query
        Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("60 Dec")

        'Supply the parameter value
        qdf.Parameters("startDate") = startDate
        qdf.Parameters("endDate") = endDate

        'Open a Recordset based on the parameter query
        Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset()

            'Check to see if the recordset actually contains rows
        If Not (rst.EOF And rst.BOF) Then
            rst.MoveFirst 'Unnecessary in this case, but still a good habit
            Do Until rst.EOF = True
                'Save contact name into a variable
                Me.tbBUDdec.Value = rst!Som
                rst.MoveNext
                Me.tbLEYdec.Value = rst!Som
                rst.MoveNext
                Me.tbMDRdec.Value = rst!Som
                rst.MoveNext
                Me.tbODCdec.Value = rst!Som
                rst.MoveNext
            Loop
        Else
            MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset."
        End If
        rst.Close 'Close the recordset
        Set rst = Nothing 'Clean up
```

**Access Query**

```sql
PARAMETERS startDate DateTime, endDate DateTime;
SELECT WarehouseCode, COUNT(DeliveryPoint) AS Som
FROM [50 resultaat]
WHERE EntryDate between [startDate] and [endDate]
GROUP BY WarehouseCode;
```

This is working fine. However, I am now trying to use the same code to call a passthrough query to a SQL server. This query uses a different syntax to declare and set the parameters:

**SQL Server query**

```sql
DECLARE @InvLineEntryDateBegin AS date
DECLARE @InvLineEntryDateEnd AS date
SET @InvLineEntryDateBegin = '2017-01-01'
SET @InvLineEntryDateEnd = '2017-05-31'

Select WarehouseCode, Count(PickOrderNr) as Som
FROM ( bla bla bla ...
```

I can't get my VBA code to work with the different SQL syntax. I've read several options but couldn't find anything concrete. Does anyone have experience with this query structure?

In other words: How can I, in VBA, insert parameters in a stored procedure that queries on a SQL server?

Comment: Did you include everything in the post except the query you want help with? That seems like a poor approach.

Comment: See this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24248870/calling-stored-procedure-while-passing-parameters-from-access-module-in-vba

Answer (score 8):

Consider building a named stored procedure that resides in SQL Server and have MS Access call it passing parameters using ADO as opposed to your current DAO method since you require parameterization. Then bind results to a recordset:

**SQL Server Stored Proc**

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE myStoredProc 
   @InvLineEntryDateBegin DATE = '2017-01-01',
   @InvLineEntryDateEnd DATE = '2017-05-31'
AS

BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;    

   SELECT WarehouseCode, Count(PickOrderNr) as Som
   FROM ( bla bla bla ... ;

END
```

**VBA**

```vb
' SET REFERENCE TO Microsoft ActiveX Data Object #.# Library
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection, cmd As ADODB.Command, rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim startDate As Date, endDate As Date   

If IsNull(Me.dpFrom) Or IsNull(Me.dpTo) Then
    MsgBox "Please select a date!", vbCritical, "MISSING DATE"
    Exit Sub
End if    
If (Me.dpFrom.Value > Me.dpTo.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Start date is bigger than the end date!", vbCritical, "INCORRECT RANGE"
    Exit Sub
End if

startDate = Me.dpFrom.Value: endDate = Me.dpTo.Value

' OPEN CONNECTION
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection         
conn.Open "DRIVER={SQL Server};server=servername;database=databasename;UID=username;PWD=password;"

' OPEN/DEFINE COMMAND OBJECT
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command     
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CommandText = "myStoredProc"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

    ' BIND PARAMETERS
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@InvLineEntryDateBegin", adDate, adParamInput, 0, startDate)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@InvLineEntryDateEnd", adDate, adParamInput, 0, endDate)
En With

' BIND RESULTS TO RECORDSET
Set rst = cmd.Execute
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply create a pass-though query in Access and save it.

Ensure that the PT query works. It will likely look like:

Exec MySpName  '2017-01-01', '2017-05-31'

Again: 100% Make sure the query works when you click on it in Access. At this point you not written any VBA code.

Once you have above pass through query working, then in VBA you can do this:

```
Dim strStartDate    As String
Dim strEndDate      As String
Dim strSQL          As String

strStartDate = "'" & Format(Me.dpFrom, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'"
strEndDate = "'" & Format(Me.dpTo, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'"


strSQL = "exec MyStoreProc " & strStartDate & "," & strEndDate

With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("QryMyPass")

  .SQL = strSQL
  Set rst = .OpenRecordset

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right, in a pass-through query, you are passing the query definition directly to the engine in which it is going to run. So, you will have to use the SQL Server syntax for your query instead of the Access VBA syntax. Give that a try.

Also, the same goes for a Stored procedure. Use the syntax like you were to execute through SSMS.

"exec sp_mysp var1 var2" and so on.